# Build Error on Azure DevOps - Solution made up of multiple target frameworks

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution, mostly made up of .NET Framework 4.5 projects.

Recently, we added a project (library) that targets both netstandard2.0 and net45.

This was achieved by making the following amendments to the .proj file of the new library.

[image: targeting]

This builds fine in VS2019, but when pushed to Azure DevOps (building using the VS2019 agent) it fails with the following error.

> Error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

[image]

Can anyone please advise?

---

Edit 1:

Here is my YAML...

```
  PublishProfile: 'VSORelease'

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution Retailer/Retailer.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: Retailer/Retailer.sln
    vsVersion: 16.0
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="$(PublishProfile)"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

It appears that (even though I am able to choose VS2019 as an option in my build pipeline)... Visual Studio 2019 isn't available on Azure DevOps?

> [warning] Visual Studio version '16.0' not found. Falling back to version '14.0'.

[image]

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Are you using the right hosted build agent? You should use the one Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019, check the queue your build definition is actually using?

Comment: This was the issue, which I found and fixed. You are welcome to add the answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Build Error on Azure DevOps - Solution made up of multiple target frameworks

Since you are using Visual Studio 2019 on your local, so you should build the solution on the Azure Devops with agent **Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019**, which with Visual Studio installed by default.

Hope this helps.